# How to print the code of an xpath matching node?

Tags: python, xpath

How do I print the full text corresponding to an xpath match, that is to say, the current node with all its children, as it appears in the source xml.

```py
from lxml.html.soupparser import fromstring

strings = '<div><svg john=doe><path d="0"></path></svg></div>'
p = fromstring(strings)
for n in p.xpath('//path'):
    print(n)
```

```sh
# Desired results
<path d="0"></path>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `html.tostring(element_goes_here)` method as shown below.

```
from lxml import html
page = """<div><svg john=doe><path d="0"></path></svg></div>"""
tree = html.fromstring(page)
for n in tree.xpath('//path'):
    print(html.tostring(n))
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Should add a caveat that this isn't guaranteed to be "as it appears in the source XML", only something that is logically equivalent. For example, attribute order may be different, redundant namespace declaration may disappear, single quotes may be replaced by double quotes, etc.